# UK Visitor visa what document i need

Tags: uk, paperwork, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

my husband is British and working in rwanda these days. Iam indian and these days on dependent(Resident visa) in Rwanda. My husband and me want to visit his mum so i applied for visitor visa it got refused stating that i had not given any evidence that i will return to rwanda. what document i need to give them

Comment: In the absence of specific refusal information in the form of your refusal notice, the canonical link fits your first port of call.